# Deploying two github repositories to single azure web app

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, github

This is not really a programmatically question, but i couldnt find any more suitable stackexchange site for it.

I have recently moved to Azure, where i deploy my backend web applications and API's. I found that it is possible to deploy multiple web services to one Azure Web App, by creating a branch with its own endpoint url, like so.

```
Normal : www.example.azurewebsites.net

New    : www.example.azurewebsites.net/newSite
```

I found it is easy to deploy my .NET services from Visual studio to the new endpoint, but does anyone know if i can deploy my git repository to this endpoint by any chance?

I am new to azure, so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: see https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/201-web-app-github-deploy/azuredeploy.json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to customize the deployment procedure a bit. Amit Apple has a good series on this. Customize your deployment script to build your temporary directory with everything you need and then deploy it. Azure will give you the deployment script to customize or you can use the azure-cli to generate one and you can customize it.

http://blog.amitapple.com/post/38417491924/azurewebsitecustomdeploymentpart1

The deployment script will use KuduSync to copy either a repository or temp folder to your wwwroot folder, so it's up to you to build this folder and have it pushed out.

https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Custom-Deployment-Script