# Connect separate Git repositories to virtual applications in Azure

Tags: git, azure, kudu

I have a regular web site (app service) in Azure which is connected to a Git repository. Now I would like to add virtual applications for APIs which reside in their own repositories.

So this is basically what I want to achieve:

```
Repository 1 -> MyWebSite
Repository 2 -> MyWebSite/api1
Repository 3 -> MyWebSite/api2
...
```

From what I have heard, this is possible with the help of Git subtrees. However, I would like to keep the repositories totally separate if possible, and deploy the projects individually with continuous delivery.

Comment: Just to be clear, you're talking about git deploy to Azure App Service?

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34083558/deploying-two-github-repositories-to-single-azure-web-app